# How to limit the item quantity on Netsuite shopping cart to available item quantity

Tags: netsuite

I want to limit the item quantity to only available item quantity while adding to cart option in Netsuite site builder so that users do not select more than what is available.

Comment: You have to add some code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real practical difficulty since the amounts available are not updated until an order is approved. That means you could have two carts both with the total available quantity of a product in them. The first cart to complete their order gets the items (if you auto approve) and the second one gets an error message or an apology notice from your customer service team.

You can limit the opportunities for this to be an issue by setting up your out-of-stock behaviour (at both the store and item level) or by putting a small amount of reserve stock into a location that is not available for fulfilling web orders. You would then use the reserve stock to fulfill orders that make it through when your web inventory is exhausted.

Whether you use reserve stock or not depends on whether you value the customer experience over clearing your stock. If you are just trying to minimize end-of-line orders you should probably used the out-of-stock behaviour controls and put time/effort into scripting automated emails that go out when an order does make it in that has out-of-stock items on it.